# Excel - COUNTIFS comparing dates does not return any values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

After searching through hundreds of `COUNTIFS` questions, I can't find the answer, so please bear with me.

I want to count the number of projects where State=Completed AND Actual End Date is Less Than Planned Finish.

Data is as follows: [image]

This statement works: `=COUNTIFS(Table1[State],"Completed",Table1[Actual End Date],">0")` (value = 75)

Changing the 2nd criteria though returns 0: `=COUNTIFS(Table1[State],"Completed",Table1[Actual End Date],"<="&Table1[Planned Finish])`

Actual value should be 31 (obtained via a helper column) but I'd like to avoid the helper column if possible - and I think that it is possible, I'm just not sure how to do so.

Comment: I use this for counting pending items last week: `=COUNTIFS(DB_Current_Status,"PENDING",DB_Start_Date,">="&Prev_Week_Start,DB_Start_Date,"<="&Prev_Week_End)` But it is comparing the columns to a value derived elsewhere. To check a list against a list usually needs an array somewhere in the mix. I also try to avoid array formulas on anything that someone else might touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The criteria cannot be a range, it must be a single value.  COUNTIFS will not work for that reason.

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[State]="Completed")*(Table1[Actual End Date]<=Table1[Planned Finish]))
```

Comment: Scott - thanks, that works.  I'll not as answer shortly.  Follow-up Questoin: why can I not use an array formula with Countifs?

Comment: @sam, it is not designed that way.  It is simplified, which is why it allows full column references without detriment to calc times.